# Couldn't find coordinate system NRW Netz zone 2 in Metashape

Tags: coordinate-system, photogrammetry

I have photogrammetry data from Germany, I got information of the coordinate system used in this project for Ground Control Point (GCP) is NRW Netz77 zone 2. I couldn't find anything on epsg.io or spatialreference.org.

I'm trying to set the coordinate system in Agisoft Metashape. Does anyone know about this coordinate system and how to set it in Metashape?

Here I attached the image from GPS controller.

[image]

Comment: https://www.geotrafo.com/index.php?page=parametersets&lang=en has them in .gpt format but how to get them in metashape is another challenge.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your information, it's great help. Yes it's another challange, until now I'm not sure how to put it into metashape.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer. I found a version of the definition at [geotrafo e.U](https://www.geotrafo.com/index.php?page=parametersets&lang=en). The downloaded file for Netz77-NRW GK2.gtp looks like this:

```
geotrafo_parameter_v46
Netz77-NRW_GK2
-566.1
-116.3
-390.1
1.11
0.24
-3.76
0.9999874
Bessel 1841
Gauss/Krüger
6
2500000
0
0
0
0
1
```

The first 7 parameters are either for a coordinate frame or a position vector transformation between DHDN and WGS84/ETRS89/ITRFxx. Checking other DHDN/WGS84 transformations, the parameters are definitely defined as FROM WGS84/ETRS89/ITRFxx TO DHDN, but the method is unclear. I can find a transformation with similar values that uses coordinate frame but usually European countries use position vector. The only difference between the 2 methods is the signs of the rotation parameters (#4, 5, 6).

The "Bessel 1841" is used for DHDN.

The projection is the Gauss-Kruger zone 2 so,

```
6 = central meridian/longitude of origin
2500000 = false easting
0 = (guess) false northing
0 = (guess- latitude of origin
0 = (I don't know)
0 = (I don't know)
1 = scale factor
```

These 7 parameters may be used for projections that take different numbers of parameters.

Comment: If someone knows how to get it into metashape, feel free to include this info into your answer or modify mine.